# Correcting user input to meet a specific requirement for Hangman

Tags: python, loops

I need the user input to only equal 1 character but there is a bug in the code that lets me enter more than one character at a time. I need to be able to prompt the user to say you can only enter one character at a time and then go back to let them enter the character but without the character counting toward the game.

```
print ("lets play guess this word.") #time to play 

secret_word = input("Enter a secret word to guess: ") # gather the secret word
secret_word = secret_word.lower() # convert to lower 
guesses = "" # this is the string that will show what has been guessed later
turns = 6 # how many chances they get to enter a wrong character. 

# a very very tricky while loop. 
while turns > 0:         # will be true until the turns counter makes turns = 0
    count = 0   # this count determines wether to print _ or the character
    for char in secret_word: # looking at characters in the secret word
        if char in guesses: #  this is used to display the correct letters and _'s
            print (char, end="")   
        else:
            print ("_ ",end="") # this print the _ for every char in secretword
            count += 1   # ends the for loop continues to the next part 
    if count == 0: # you won the game end the loop. 
        print ()
        print ("You win")  
        break              
    print ()
    print ()
    print ()
    guess = input("guess a character:")
    count2 = 0
    if len(guess) > 1:
        count2 += 1
        while count2 > 0:
            print ("you can only guess 1 character at a time")
            count2 -= 1
    guess = guess.lower()  #lower        # it is time to guess the letters. 
    guesses += guess                  
    if guess not in secret_word:  # if statement for if guess is not in word
        turns -= 1       # subtract from turns
        print ()
        print ()
        print ("Wrong")   
        print ("Letters guessed so far: ",guesses) # end of loop show guessed letters
        print ("You have", + turns, 'more guesses') # show turns left
        if turns == 0:   # END GAME        
            print ("The word was",secret_word,"You Loose")
```

Screenshot showing the code does work in  Python:

[image: code working in Python]

I also need help with making it only accept 1 character at a time and also no numbers. I also added this part of code while trying to accomplish this task but it does not stop the multiple characters being entered from counting toward the word.

```
count2 = 0
    if len(guess) > 1:
        count2 += 1
        while count2 > 0:
            print ("you can only guess 1 character at a time")
            count2 -= 1
```

Here is my output:

```
lets play guess this word.
Enter a secret word to guess: computer
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 


guess a character:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
you can only guess 1 character at a time


Wrong
Letters guessed so far:  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
You have 5 more guesses
computer
You win
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you're missing is the statement to loop back around after warning if the user enters invalid input. With the structure you've got, the statement you want is `continue`, which jumps to the next iteration of a loop:

```
while turns > 0:
    # Print current guesses; get input; etc...

    # Check for invalid input
    if len(guess) > 1:
        print("you can only guess 1 character at a time")
        continue  # This makes us return to the top of the while loop.

    # We definitely have valid input by the time we get here, so handle the new guess.
```

---

This is simplified a little from your version; I've taken out `count2`, for instance, because it wasn't doing anything important. But the premise is the same: after you warn the user about their invalid input, you need to ask for *new* input--jump to the top of the loop--instead of just moving ahead.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something stupid simple like that, but could no t figure it out.